# How to add a table and save data to an existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I used code first approach to create a database (that created "User.mdf" file that include a table called "users").

I added a new model:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int pictureId { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string pictureUrl { get; set; }
}

public class PictureDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

And tried to save data in a new table like this:

```
Picture curentImage = new Picture();
        curentImage.userId = int.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
        curentImage.pictureUrl = "/MyImages" + filename;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pictures.Add(curentImage);
            db.SaveChanges();   
        }
```

I expected that it will create a new table for Pictures (as it worked in the user model)...

What is needed for making "EF magic" to know this model too 
and to create and add a Pictures table in the existing database? 
Will be happy to get an answer with the right way to save that data to a new table and few explantion if possible.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is something not working?

Comment: I thought the title will be enough as a question, but I'll edit the message to include the question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *probably* getting an error because the migration are turned off.

You could write your own migration to add the new table or you could use the automigrate feature of EF Code first.

If you want to write your own migration code you can read on this blog on own to do it:
[Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx)

If you want to enable auto-migration. You can add this configuration class and it should do the trick.

```
internal sealed class PictureDBContextConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PictureDBContext>
{
    public PictureDBContextConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; // This will allow CodeFirst to create the missing tables/columns
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;  //This will allow CodeFirst to Drop column or even drop tables
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Added your code to my Picture class but still the table hasn't created. I know I get a Picture object right, then my code is:
`if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Pictures.Add(curentImage);
                db.SaveChanges();   
            }
`
Is that OK?

Comment: I can see the watch window but there are no exceptions

Comment: Didn't get any exception (or I'm not looking in the right place...). Every thing seems to work fine but the new table refuse to be born... Is there somewhere I can send you the project? (if it's OK by the rules of StackOverflow and by you)

Comment: I was a beginner, that's why I didn't even understand what I've done wrong. The right way of doing things is to create the model, then just run Update Database (and of course having migration enabled...) and it will do all the magic for you.